# Orientdb User Friend design schema

Tags: graph, orientdb, nosql

I want to design User & Friend relationship in OrientDB.
I have 1 Vertex User & 1 Edge Friend.
Here I do in the console

```
create class User extends V
create class Friend extends E
```

I create 10 User (from User_0 until User_9)

```
create vertex User set name='User_0'
create vertex User set name='User_1'
create vertex User set name='User_2'
create vertex User set name='User_3'
create vertex User set name='User_4'
create vertex User set name='User_5'
create vertex User set name='User_6'
create vertex User set name='User_7'
create vertex User set name='User_8'
create vertex User set name='User_9'
```

Then I create the edge Friend

```
create edge Friend from #11:0 to #11:1
create edge Friend from #11:0 to #11:2
create edge Friend from #11:0 to #11:3
create edge Friend from #11:0 to #11:4
create edge Friend from #11:0 to #11:5
create edge Friend from #11:1 to #11:0
create edge Friend from #11:1 to #11:2
create edge Friend from #11:1 to #11:3
create edge Friend from #11:1 to #11:4
create edge Friend from #11:1 to #11:5
create edge Friend from #11:1 to #11:6
```

First question:  If User_0 friend with User_1, do we need to store both of them in Edge?  In example above, I store user #11:0 to #11:1, and #11:1 to #11:0 (2 Edge).  I do this in traditional database (MySQL), I want to know the best practice in NoSQL (OrientDB that I use now).  Or just save with 1 row for user #11:0 to #11:1 (1 Edge only).

Second, how I get all the friends of User_0?  Provide sql select example, please.  I want the result out array of user @RID & other fields of friend of User_0.  So the query will be same for all User to get all friends (if we design Friend edge with 2 row Edge, #11:0 to #11:1 and #11:1 to #11:0).

If the design is 1 row Edge for both of Friend, it will be different, the query for User_0 how, and User_1 how to get all friends.  But skip this if we store 2 friend relationship in 2 row of edge).

Third question, How I can get my friend mutual friends (that means the friends of my friend are my friends too).  So, User_0 if see User_1 friends, the mutual friends are #11:2,#11:3,#11:4,#11:5. #11,6 is not mutual friend User_1 of User_0.

I think sample just 6 or less user is enough, but I already created 10 users.

Thanks!

Comment: wow... none don't know?

Comment: Have I answered your question ?

Comment: see my comment below your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is fine. Two user vertices and a friend edge is enough to achieve this. It will take less storage.

I would use a linklist to store the friend request received and sent in each users. A User has multiple friendrequest.

Document API :

```
traverse IsFriendsWith from #10:1234 while $depth <= 3 strategy BREADTH_FIRST
```

Graph API :

```
    select from (
      select 
        expand(unionall(
          outE("IsFriendsWith").inV(), 
          inE("IsFriendsWith").outV()
        ))
        from (
          select 
              expand(unionall(
                outE("IsFriendsWith").inV(), 
                inE("IsFriendsWith").outV()
              ))
          from (
             select expand($u) let $u = first((select from User where uuid = "1"))
          )
        )
    )
  )

      where @rid <> $u and @rid NOT IN $u.both("IsFriendsWith")
```

Above query taken from [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685205/find-friends-of-friends-with-orientdb-sql)

Check out the [social network domain](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Traverse.html#social-network-domain) in the 
documentation for more information.

Comment: sorry, so two user vertices and one or two edge?  If A friend to B, 2 vertices, it is correct, but the edge should be one or two?  from A to B only, or from A to B and from B to A?