# Visualizing graph with OrientDB Studio

Tags: orientdb

I'm working with OrientDB (2.2.10) and occasionaly I would like to visually inspect my dataset to make sure I'm doing things correctly. On this page of OrientDB http://orientdb.com/orientdb/ you see a nice visualization of a large graph with the following query:

```
select * from V limit -1;
```

So I tried the same query on my dataset but the result is so extremely sluggish that I can't work with it. My dataset is not extremely large (few hundred vertices, couple thousand edges) but still the result is unworkable. I tried all major browsers but with all I have the same result. Also my computer is not underpowered, I have a quad-core i7 with 16GB RAM.

As a very simple example I have the following graph: 
BAR --WITHIN---> CITY --LOCATED_IN--> COUNTRY

Here: [Find "friends of friends" with OrientDB SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685205/find-friends-of-friends-with-orientdb-sql) I was able to get at least an example of how to do this type of query on a graph. I managed to get a subset of my graph for example as follows:

```
select expand(
bothE('WITHIN').bothV()
) from Bar where barName='Foo' limit -1
```

This get's me the graph of 1 Bar vertex, the edge WITHIN and the City vertex. But if I now want to go one step further by also fetching the country which the city is located in I cannot get this style of query to work for me. I tried this:

```
select expand(
bothE('WITHIN').bothV()
.bothE('LOCATED_IN').bothV()
) from Bar where barName='Foo' limit -1
```

This results in the same subset being shown. However, if I first run the first query and then without clearing the canvas run the second query I do get the 3 vertices. So it seems I'm close but I would like to get all 3 vertices and it's edges in one query, not having to run first the one and then the other. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all three vertices, it would be much easier start from the middle (city) and than get in and out to get bar and contry. I've tried with a similar little structure: [image: OrientDB Bar Structure]

To get city, bar name and country you can try a query like this:

```
select name, in("WITHIN").name as barName,out("LOCATED_IN").name as barCountry from (select from City where name='Milan') unwind barName, barCountry
```

And the output will be:

[image: OrientDB Bar Query Output]

Hope it helps.
If it is not suitable for your case, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr and Alessandro both for your answers. I'm going to try them both tonight and see what works best for me! What I'm still struggling with is that both of your solutions appear to be quite different, one with the "traverse" keyword, the other with the "unwind" keyword. I'm having a hard time finding a guide or tutorial where these concepts are explained and which is better for which situation. Do you maybe have some links to some online resources where these concepts are explained? Thanks!

Comment: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Traverse.html   /     http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html#unwinding

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the links. It's not completely clear for me yet what to use in which situation but I guess I just have to build up a bit of experience here :)

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, one more follow-up question if that's ok. I can get the query working but only in the "browse" tab of the OrientDB studio. I would like to see the result in the form of a (visual) graph. But when I run the same query there I get no results. Running the traverse query from Alessandro does get me visual results but I have to add "limit -1" to get some real results (and make sure not to set the depth too high). However, I'd like to have some control over what gets selected as your query suggests. Any idea how to tweak your query to get visual results? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
traverse * from (select from bar where barName='Foo') while $depth <= 4
```

Example: I tried with this little graph

[image]

and I got

[image: enter code here]

Hope it helps.